# okhttp onResponse access to local variable

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I need to get the string from the `onResponse` method in `okhttp` call, but I can not change the value inside the `onResponse`. My code is below

```
public class OkHttpTest {

private static final String TAG = "OkHttpTest";
OkHttpClient mClient = new OkHttpClient();

public String getMarkets(String url) throws IOException {
    public static String mString;
    Request mRequest = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    Call mCall = mClient.newCall(mRequest);
    mCall.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: call failed");
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: ok");
                mString = response.body().string();  // cannot access
            } else return;
        }
    });
    return mString;  //
}   
}
```

I'm calling like this

```
 String result = test.getMarkets(url);
```

Is there any way that I can make this work ?

Comment: can you provide the logs

Comment: share the logs + try to log the response to make sure that's your code is working fine

Comment: Its mString to be declared final , if i declare it as final then i cannot change the values in onResponse

Comment: I know it's a little late, but i can help you if you still have the problem, do you need to modify the value of mString?

Comment: i got it working. thanks

Comment: @sandeepcmsm, If you got it working, it would be nice if you post the solution and accept your answer. This way you help other people and the question is not popping up as un answered forever.